# FIX Message with sequence #1 is too low (expected sequence #2)

Tags: java, bloomberg, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm using QuickFixJ to post messages on Bloomberg on to sessions with differents IPs. I'm able to connect on both sessions   but when I try to send messages, I'm getting the error :

Received logout request: Message with sequence #1 is too low (expected sequence #2)

My configuration file :

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/quickfixlogs
FileLogPath=target/data/quickfixlogs
ConnectionType=initiator
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=****
TargetCompID=****

[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=****
TargetCompID=*****
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SessionQualifier=****
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=10
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ReconnectInterval=5
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
SocketConnectPort=8228
SocketConnectHost=69.191.198.38
SocketKeyStore=*****
SocketKeyStorePassword=*****
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
KeyStoreType=JKS

[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=*****
TargetCompID=*****
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SessionQualifier=*****
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=10
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ReconnectInterval=5
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
SocketConnectPort=8228
SocketConnectHost=69.191.230.38
SocketKeyStore=*****
SocketKeyStorePassword=*****
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
KeyStoreType=JKS
```

I have tried setting the ResetSeqNumFlag=Y/N but I am still getting the same error message.

Bloomberg's documentation states that :

Bloomberg adheres to the standard usage of the ResetSeqNumFlag(141) for maintaining 24-hr sessions
according to the "FIX Transport 1.1" specification (https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/fixt/ ). Below
are excerpts from the FIXT1.1 specification:
It is recommended that a new FIX session be established once within each 24 hour period. It is
possible to maintain 24 hour connectivity and establish a new set of sequence numbers by
sending a Logon message with the ResetSeqNumFlag set.
When using the ResetSeqNumFlag to maintain 24 hour connectivity and establish a new set of
sequence numbers, the process should be as follows. Both sides should agree on a reset time
and the party that will be the initiator of the process. Note that the initiator of the ResetSeqNum
process may be different than the initiator of the Logon process. One side will initiate the process
by sending a TestRequest and wait for a Heartbeat in response to ensure of no sequence number
gaps. Once the Heartbeat has been received, the initiator should send a Logon with
ResetSeqNumFlag set to Y and with MsgSeqNum of 1. The acceptor should respond with a
Logon with ResetSeqNumFlag set to Y and with MsgSeqNum of 1. At this point new messages
from either side should continue with MsgSeqNum of 2. It should be noted that once the
initiator sends the Logon with the ResetSeqNumFlag set, the acceptor must obey this request
and the message with the last sequence number transmitted “yesterday” may no longer be
available. The connection should be shut down and manual intervention taken if this process is
initiated but not followed properly.

But I cannot see how to send a TestRequest and wait for a HeartBeat/ send a heartbeat when only when receiving the testrequest in order to synchronize sequence numbers.

My application code is as follows :

```
public class QuickFixJApplication implements Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogon(SessionID sessionID) {
   
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogout(SessionID sessionID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void fromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon {

    }

    @Override
    public void toApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws DoNotSend {

    }

    @Override
    public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {

    }
}
```

The code I'm using to configure the session :

```
public class FixConfiguration {

    public static final String quickfixj = "quickfixj.cfg";

    public ThreadedSocketInitiator threadedSocketInitiator(QuickFixJApplication application, String fileName){
        ThreadedSocketInitiator threadedSocketInitiator = null;
        try {
            SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            MessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
            LogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(settings);
            MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
            threadedSocketInitiator = new ThreadedSocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return threadedSocketInitiator;
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to publishing prices :

```
public class BloombergPricePublisher {

    public ThreadedSocketInitiator threadedSocketInitiator;
    public QuickFixJApplication application;

    /**
     * Constructeur de BloombergPricePublisher qui prend en paramètres :
     * @param application : l'application QuickFixJ initialisée
     * */
    public BloombergPricePublisher(QuickFixJApplication application, ThreadedSocketInitiator threadedSocketInitiator){
        super();
        this.application = application;
        this.threadedSocketInitiator = threadedSocketInitiator;
    }

    /**
     * Méthode de publication d'un prix sur Bloomberg
     * */
    public void publish(MarketPrice marketPrice) {

        MarketDataIncrementalRefresh marketDataIncrementalRefresh = createMarketDataIncrementalRefresh(marketPrice);

        try{
            for (SessionID sessionID : this.threadedSocketInitiator.getSessions()){

                    Session.sendToTarget(marketDataIncrementalRefresh, sessionID);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Méthode de création d'un nouveau prix pour le publier sur Bloomberg
     * @param marketPrice
     * */
    public MarketDataIncrementalRefresh createMarketDataIncrementalRefresh(MarketPrice marketPrice) {

        quickfix.fix50sp2.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh();

        quickfix.fix50sp2.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries group = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries();

        /**
         * Ajout prix Bid au message
         * */
        group.set(new MDUpdateAction('1'));
        group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
        group.set(new MDEntryPx(marketPrice.getBid_kech()));
        group.set(new Symbol(marketPrice.getCUSIP()));
        message.addGroup(group);

        /**
         * Ajout prix Ask au message
         * */
        group.set(new MDUpdateAction('1'));
        group.set(new MDEntryType('1'));
        group.set(new MDEntryPx(marketPrice.getAsk_kech()));
        group.set(new Symbol(marketPrice.getCUSIP()));
        message.addGroup(group);

        return message;

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: You have multiple questions rolled into one here. That makes it difficult to answer. The initial problem with the seqnum too low: actually you only need to check where and why you sent a message with seqnum 1 before. A possible explanation for that could be that you reset your seqnums at a different time. Please agree on a time where the session is getting reset and configure that in `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Make sure you use the same timezone as your counterparty.

Comment: Okay thank you very much Christoph I'll try it out !

Comment: Hello Christoph, I was able to check with Bloomberg they said that they only reset the connection  on weekends at 12AM New York time and that therefore the issue was not on their side. In fact, I'm sending seqNum= 1 to login. I'm posting my entire code to login in a new question.

Comment: wait a minute. which "code to login"? there shouldn't be any code necessary to do that. QFJ will do that on its own. To reset the session only once per week is a config issue not a code issue.

Comment: Is it possible to reset the connection only on weekends?

Comment: OK, no offense since you are new to StackOverflow but could you stop opening various questions for the same problem? Close either this or the other question. Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry didn't mean any wrongdoing I didn't know the procedure I'll read the documentation thanks !

Comment: I deleted the other question

Comment: OK, thanks. Two things: 1. what happens if you removed the generation of the Heartbeat from your `onLogon()` callback? 2. What is the exact question that you have? Is it the one with the heartbeat/testrequest below the quote from the FIX spec?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had removed the onLogon() heartbeat generation in the most recent code ! My question would be either : How to configure quickfixj to avoid getting a sequence # too low error?  
Or :
what is wrong with my current configuration which is causing the error?

Comment: I'd try the following: ask Bloomberg to disable the 24h schedule with the reset via ResetSeqNum flag. Then agree on a schedule with them and configure it accordingly via StartTime, EndTime, StartDay, EndDay. Do not forget to configure the correct time zone or there will be problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @ChristophJohn, I contacted Bloomberg and am awaiting their response !

Comment: While awaiting Bloomberg's reply, I tried setting ResetOnLogon=Y which solves the sequence number error but I can't see messages published on Bloomberg in the messages log file is this normal?

Comment: In general you don't want to reset on every logon.

Comment: Hello @ChristophJohn Bloomberg were uncooperative on this one and argued that since the feed was working now, there was no need to synchronize our times. And yet, I tried setting these as part of my solution so it should be contributing to the feed working. I'm posting the new configuration file in case it can help someone. I'm now having trouble with messages not sent (log file only showing heartbeats and no messages sent and am trying to find a solution...) Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration file solves the issue :

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/quickfix/messages
FileLogPath=target/data/quickfix/logs
ConnectionType=initiator
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=*****
TargetCompID=*****

[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=*****
TargetCompID=*****
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SessionQualifier=*****
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
TimeZone=America/New_York
StartDay=Monday
EndDay=Monday
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
SocketConnectPort=8228
SocketConnectHost=69.191.198.38
SocketKeyStore=/home/******
SocketKeyStorePassword=****
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
KeyStoreType=JKS

[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=*****
TargetCompID=*****
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SessionQualifier=*****
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
TimeZone=America/New_York
StartDay=Monday
EndDay=Monday
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
SocketConnectPort=8228
SocketConnectHost=69.191.230.38
SocketKeyStore=/home/*****
SocketKeyStorePassword=*****
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
KeyStoreType=JKS
```